# How is the built-in Function object approach uses substantially more memory than the function literal?

Tags: javascript

Below snippet defines a function `Robot()` that is used as an object constructor—a function that creates an object.

```
function Robot(robotName) {
   this.name = robotName;
   this.sayHi = function () { console.log("Hi my name is "+this.name); };
   this.sayBye = function () { console.log("Bye!"); };
   this.sayAnything = function (msg) { console.log(this.name+" says "+msg); };
}
```

The second approach is

```
function Robot(robotName) {
    this.name = robotName;
    this.sayHi = new Function ("console.log('Hi my name is '+this.name); ");
    this.sayBye = new Function ("console.log('Bye!'); ");
    this.sayAnything = new Function("msg","console.log(this.name+' says '+msg);" );
}
```

The book which I am reading says -

> The only downside to 2nd approach is that it will **use substantially
>   more memory**, as **new function objects** are created every time you create
>   a new instance of the Robot object.

I see when I do like below-

```
var wally = new Robot("Wally");
```

In **both** the approaches, wally robot has **3 function objects**.

```
wally.sayHi();    //1
wally.sayAnything("I don't know what to say");   //2
wally.sayBye();   //3
```

How is the `2nd approach` **uses substantially more memory** then?

Comment: Get a new book if that is the “only downside”. If it does use more memory (and how much) depends on specific implementation.

Comment: in the first ones functions are prototype

Comment: No, they are not ‘prototype’. They are new functions assigned in the ctor to the new object - no prototype chain is utilized. Maybe the wrong example is being compared?

Answer (score 2):

When code gets parsed it'll be turned into an internal representation that the engine is able to execute. Now for regular code that happens once when the code is loaded. If you dynamically turn strings into code (as with `Function`) that happens when `Function()` is called, so each time your constructor gets called. Therefore using the second approach the engine has to create & keep another internal representation of the code, so if you create 10.000 instances, there will have to be 10.000 code representations. Additionally, this will not only eat up memory, it will also degrade performance, as optimizations are done on a per function basis, and the parsing of code also takes time, so the second approach will probably execute much much slower (yes, the engine *could* optimize those differences away, but I guess it probably won't).

There are a few other downsides:

1) No syntax highlighting from your IDE

2) unreadable code

So never, never, never ever use the second version. And get a new book as:

1) It makes no sense to learn how to dynamically create functions from strings, you will never have to use it.

2) It says that the second is worse because "new function objects are created every time you create a new instance of the Robot object", which applies to both the first and the second snippet (so thats not really a reason).

Answer (score 0):

it's more about how javascript works.

As you know, on first launch, javascript create AST, and optimises code. So, in first case, function will be "precompiled" once. In second, AST and "precompilation" will be done every time

Comment: Chrome (and maybe others) will actual store functions “as text” and re-parse them in certain situations. Having an AST built and kept around uses more memory.

Answer (score -2):

Most engines will create a new stack frame (more memory) as it has to invoke the interpreter for each `new Function("")` call, with an an anonymous IIFE (harder to debug) . It's similar to using `eval()`. Besides the memory issues, it allows for injection attacks and can also cause scope issues depending on strict mode.